# Nikon D5100 struggling to autofocus on screen, but fine through viewfinder?

Tags: nikon, autofocus, troubleshooting, sigma

hope you can help me and my frustrating issue

I have a D5100 with a Sigma 18-250mm f/3.5-6.3 dc os lens which will AF no problem at all when I'm looking through the viewfinder but when I change to live view mode on the screen the lens adjusts only a fraction at a time, and sometimes not reaching focus at all. When it does focus it can be 10-20 seconds by which time my shot is gone! It's obviously not a lighting/exposure issue as I have no problem focussing through the viewfinder.

I hope someone can shed some light on this issue for me?

Comment: [Different camera model, same basic issue](https://photo.stackexchange.com/q/103282/15871)

Comment: Related: [Why do mirrorless cameras have quicker autofocus than SLRs using live view?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/q/34567/15871) and [Why is on sensor PDAF drastically slower than traditional PDAF?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/q/38717/15871)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not totally unexpected.. with the viewfinder the camera uses [phase detection focus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Autofocus#Phase_detection) using specialized sensors. In liveview mode, the AF sensors aren't usable (they only see the light when the mirror is down) and the camera uses [contrast detection focus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Autofocus#Contrast_detection) which is slower[*] and doesn't work too well in low light or if the subject lacks contrast (at least on cameras as old as a D5100...)

[*] The slowness of the contrast-detection focus is what kept the DSLR popular...

Comment: Related photo-se question: [What is the practical difference between phase-detect and contrast-based autofocus?](//photo.stackexchange.com/q/20474),